# why fill data into buffer grow from low to high address

Tags: memory-address

When we call a function, its stack is something like:

```
LOW MEMORY ADDRESS
localvariables
saved frame pointer
return address
.... 
HIGH MEMORY ADDRESS
```

Why does it fill data into a buffer the direction is from low to high memory address?

Many people tell me: "because this is how it works", but I think someone in some book or other has written why we have this behavior but I'm unable to find a good resource about.

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding or confusing a few things.

1. in you example you seem to mix up, operation system functionality with program and compiler operation.

If you allocate multiple memory addresses there is always a lower address and a higher address. You can only change that by writing everything to the same address which might result in a very limited or useless program.

2. there are many buffer implementations, depending on your programming language, framework, ...

which one you choose is up to you, if you use a buffer that is already implemented in a library, of course you have the follow the rules this buffer adds data, because that is how **THIS** specific buffer works. If you are not happy by how this is done, you need to change the chosen buffer or even the whole library or in extreme cases write your own buffer.

3. how to add data to a buffer

some buffers allow you to add data anywhere in the buffer, at the cost of e.g. performance or reliability. If you wish to do it that way its up to you.

Comment: thank you for the answer, however my question is simple, in a condition(for example) like buffer overflow when we fill a buffer, why it grow from low to high address?  please do not tag this question duplicate and link to:https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/82750/why-are-buffer-overflows-executed-in-the-direction-they-are because I want to know why buffer is filled from low to high address when we put something.

Comment: like I said it depends on the implementation of the buffer you are using